Question to proof of Artin-Schreier
I was reading an introduction of real spectrum , which mentioned the following theorem on page 3:

Theorem 1. (Artin-Schreier) Any formally real field admits at least one ordering.

I have attached the proof below. I'm very confused of some details in the proof of Lemma 2. In particular,


why is $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ in $T[-a]$, is it becauce $\frac{1}{t}\in T[-a]$? I don't understand why $T[-a]$ contains $-1$
The last sentence of the proof for Lemme 2 is also confusing to me. I don't know how we get $a = -y^{-2}(1+a) \in -T$
Also in the end it claimed $T \cup -T = F$. Is this because $T[a]$ and $T[-a]$ cannot both be preorderings? I'm not sure why.


I tried searching for the theorem stated in a similar manner but cannot find anything. I'm new to this and certainly does not have good intuitions, so I found it a little confusing.

We will sketch the proof, if only to emphasize that it does not in any sense construct an ordering on a formally real field. Rather, given a formally real field, what we can produce is a canonical preordering. A preordering is a subset $T \subset F$ satisfying axioms (a), (b) and (d) for orderings, but in place of (c) the weaker:
$\left(c^{\prime}\right) \sum_{\square} \subset T$.
Now what is clear is that a field is formally real iff $\sum_{\square}$ is a preordering on $F$. Moreover, this is the unique minimal preordering in any formally real field. The union of a chain of preorderings is itself a preordering, so Zorn's Lemma ${ }^4$ entitles us to a preordering which is not properly contained in any other preordering, and the point is to show that any maximal preordering does in fact satisfy the property $T \cup(-T)=F$, so gives an ordering. For this we need:
Lemma 2. For a preordering $T \subset F$ and an element $a \in F$, the following are equivalent:
(i) the set $T[a]=\{x+y a \mid x, y \in T\}$ is a preordering;
(ii) $a$ is not in $-T$.
Proof: Since no preordering can contain both $a$ and $-a$, (i) $\Longrightarrow$ (ii) is clear. Convsersely, suppose $a$ is not in $-T$. We claim that -1 is not in $T[a]$, which is enough, since if $T[-a]$ contained any nonzero element $t$ and its additive inverse $-t$, it would contain $-t \cdot t \cdot \frac{1}{t^2}=-1$. Now, if $-1=x+y a$, then $-y a=1+x$ is a nonzero element of $T$, so $a=-y^{-2}(1+x) \in-T$, a contradiction.
Thus a maximal preordering $T \subset F$ must satisfy $T \cup-T=F$, i.e., $T$ is an ordering. This completes the proof of the Artin-Schreier theorem. In fact, we showed more:

Please do not answer in the comments, @Asigan.
